# table view is black when having multiple sections

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode5

I'm trying to have my tableView within my view controller return multiple sections. However whenever I do this and end up putting text in the section header, I get a black screen but no errors. However, changing down to one section and no header text entered in the storyboard or in code, will show the tableview correctly. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        return @"Header1";
    }
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        return @"Header2";
    }
    return nil;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 4;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    long num = indexPath.row;
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    switch (num)
    {
        case 0:
            cell = self.firstCell;
            break;
        case 1:
            cell = self.secondCell;
            break;
        case 2:
            cell = self.thirdCell;
            break;
        case 3:
            cell = self.fourthCell;
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It is not the problem of multiple `section`. You are not iniliazing `cell`. First Intialize `cell` then use it.

Comment: Please try to initialize cell to display values in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cell is not initilized so first intilize it. And for more info see this code.

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
      if(indexPath.section == 0)
      {

            static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            if (!cell)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            }
            switch (indexPath.row)
            {
                case 0:
                    cell = self.firstCell;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cell = self.secondCell;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cell = self.thirdCell;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cell = self.fourthCell;
                    break;
            }
            return cell;
}
else
{
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (!cell)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
        switch (indexPath.row)
        {
            case 0:
                cell = self.firstCell;
                break;
            case 1:
                cell = self.secondCell;
                break;
            case 2:
                cell = self.thirdCell;
                break;
            case 3:
                cell = self.fourthCell;
                break;
        }
        return cell;
     }
}
```

Comment: This works but when I add the cells for the second section, the cells from the first section disappear and are in the second section instead. The cells that are supposed to be in the second section are nowhere to be found

Comment: [It looks like this](http://i.imgur.com/bEKVurv.png) when I add four new cells to go with the second section

Comment: Now Please try to see my edited code.You knw this is happing due to switch case suppose your indexpath is 4 in that case what case of switch case will be execute . So You need to add defualt case in your switch case..